# drawtext ffmpeg 'Unable to parse graph description substring'

Tags: ffmpeg

hi im trying to add text to live video stream but i keep getting error with my command, i already tried `-filter_complex` but no success

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img1.jpg -vf 'pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2:[0:v]drawtext='text=hello:fontsize=90:x=20:y=20:fontcolor=white@0.2'' -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -x264opts keyint=40 -acodec aac -strict -2 -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/test -y -stats -report`

the error i get is

`Unable to parse graph description substring: "drawtext=text=freedome:fontsize=90:x=20:y=20:fontcolor=white@0.2"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple filterchains, where one filter operates upon the output of an earlier filter, no input pads (like `[0:v]`) should be used. Also, there is an errant colon at the end of the pad filter. It should be a comma instead, so

```
-vf 'pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2,drawtext=text="hello":fontsize=90:x=20:y=20:fontcolor=white@0.2'
```

In drawtext, you may need to specify a font if fontconfig is not available on your system.

Comment: thanks it worked great